# Read and write files to sharepoint using Azure cloud services

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I want to read and write files from/to sharepoint server. As of my knowledge we cannt use ADF to write back to sharepoint server, but we can read from sharepoint.

How we can achieve both reading and writing using azure cloud services? Please suggest best possible solutions for this.can we use python script? can we use python script? if yes, How can we use that python script in ADF and schedule?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, ADF supports only reading from sharepoint via web activity and doesnt support write back as REST end point is not supported as sink.

In case if you need low code technology, then Azure logic is the best fit which supports reading and writing back into sharepoint.

Others Azure offerings like Azure functions, Azure databricks, Azure automation and Azure batch support custom code and based on custom logics , you can read and write from sharepoint based on the code you write

yes, you can use python script to read and write data into sharepoint. You can write your python code in Azure batch or Azure function or Databricks notebooks and call them via the respective activities within ADF and schedule it